# Unusual character in my data. How can I read it?

Tags: r, ggplot2

There seems to be an unusual character in my data . how can I deal with it? It prvents me for creating a plot

```
# Create the bar chart with counts inside the bars
ggplot(comtable, aes(x = Var1)) +
  geom_bar(fill = "purple") +
  geom_text(stat = "count", aes(label = ..count.., vjust = -0.5), size = 5, color = "black") +
  labs(title = "Distribution of Comune")

Warning messages:
1: In grid.Call(C_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y,  : invalid input 'CARR�' in 'utf8towcs'
2: In grid.Call(C_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y,  : invalid input 'CARR�' in 'utf8towcs'

head(comtable)
                      Var1 Freq
1                 CARR\xd9   11
2   MONTALDO DI MONDOV\xcc    1
3                 CARD\xc8    3
4   SAN MICHELE MONDOV\xcc    4
5 SAN NICOL\xd2 D'ARCIDANO    1
6      MASER\xc0 DI PADOVA    1


dput(comtable[1,1])
structure(1L, levels = c("CARR\xd9", "MONTALDO DI MONDOV\xcc", 
"CARD\xc8", "SAN MICHELE MONDOV\xcc", "SAN NICOL\xd2 D'ARCIDANO"
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your `dput(comtable)` seems incomplete. What does `Encoding(comtable$Var1)` return? How did you create the `comtable` data.frame? Did you import the data from somewhere? Do you know what encoding was using for the strings that you imported? What do you want these values to look like on the plot? You probably want to go back and make sure you import the data with the correct encoding.

Comment: Error in Encoding(comtable$Var1) : a character vector argument expected

Comment: str(comtable)
'data.frame': 1644 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ Var1: Factor w/ 1644 levels "CARR\xd9","MONTALDO DI MONDOV\xcc",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ Freq: int  11 1 3 4 1 1 2 2 4 1 ...

Comment: dput(comtable[1,1]) gives me a very large result while I ask only for one cell

Comment: If seems your Var1 column is a factor. Again, how did you import this data into R? Did you explicitly create the factor yourself? Maybe `Encoding(levels(comtable$Var1))` but that will probably return "unknown" because it doesn't look like the data was imported correctly.

Comment: check the image I added on Q. I only know this excel file eas sent to me by Italy and I used table() to create comtable

Comment: Please edit your question and paste the output from `dput(head(comtable,10))` into a [code block]. We can't use an image of data for anything other than to see that you used `readr::read_csv("an13.csv")`, but without the CSV file itself, who's to say. As an alternative (or in addition), open the CSV file with a text editor (perhaps RStudio's editor) and copy the first 10 or so rows and paste into a code block. It might work ...

Comment: If you are getting weird characters, chances are good the file is not UTF-8 encoded. You should ask whoever created the file what encoding was used.

Comment: i found that italian causes the issue for example the last character in MONTALDO DI MONDOVÌ . what can I do?